# how to use GetDlgItemText inside and outside of worker thread

Tags: multithreading, mfc, gettext

I am having a problem with using GetDlgGetItemText inside a worker thread. it is working perfectly fine outside with

```
TCHAR txtbuff[50];
GetDlgItemText(IDC_SLIDER1, txtbuff, 50);
SOmething = ::SendMessage(something,WM_SETTEXT,0,(LPARAM)txtbuff)
```

but when i try to use the same in a worker thread I get told that it doesn't take 3 arguments, because it needs it's HWND handle (from what I have gathered), which I thought was gained using winspy++ or similar, but those handles change all the time. I thought (quite wrongly because I am new to this) that I could simply use the same code inside my worker thread. how come the above code works fine outside of the worker thread? I have looked around everywhere, am I missing something blatantly obvious/simple?

Comment: Although I could give you an answer - I would say that only the thread that created the window should interact with it. Calling `GetDlgItemText` from a worker thread is a bad idea.

Comment: Your compilation problem doesn't have anything with threading. In the main thread you call `CWnd::GetDlgItemText` function, because this is done in CWnd-derived class method. Thread function is static or global, and calls `GetDlgItemText` API, which requires HWND. Pass HWND to the thread using thread paramener.

Answer (score 0):

The GetDlgItemText version that needs only 3 arguments is a CWnd member function. MFC translates it into the 4-argument API version using the m_hWnd member of the CWnd. So you cannot use the 3 argument version outside of a CWnd object.

Another problem is that both versions of GetDlgItemText are defined to work only for accessing child windows. So you cannot use them unless calling in the context of the parent window of the IDC_SLIDER1 control.

And another problem is that MFC does not support accessing a window/control from a thread that did not create the window. There are some limited cases where this works but it is poor practice. Even when it works it causes unobvious interactions between the threads, possibly leading to a deadlock.

Put all of your interactions with the GUI into the main thread. And put all your interactions with child windows (i.e. controls) in the parent window class.

Comment: It's not MFC that lacks support for cross-thread windowing operations, it is the window manager built into the system.